# React JS - Efficient way of passing data and to another constant variable

Tags: reactjs

I got an input on another component, I want to pass the value of input on account() when changing value to the constant setSales which is on sales_add(). How would I do that? What is the efficient way of passing the data between components? Where am I wrong? Is my question possible on achieving it? if its possible, Is it recommended or bad practice? Sorry completely newbie on reactjs.

Sales Add component

```
export default function sales_add() {

    const [Sales, setSales] = useState("")

    render(
        <h1>{console.log(Sales)}</h1>
    )
}
```

Account component

```
import SalesAdd from "pages/Sales-Add/index";

export default function account (){
    const onchangeValue = async (e) => {
        const response = SalesAdd.setSales(e.target.value)
    }
    render(
        <Input type="text" className="form-control" onChange={(e) => { onchange(e) }}/>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Que is not clear but i think you want to do this ->

```
import SalesAdd from "pages/Sales-Add/index";

export default function account (){
    const onchangeValue = async (e) => {
        const response = SalesAdd.setSales(e.target.value)
    }
    render(
        <Input type="text" className="form-control" onChange={onchangeValue}/>
    )
}
```

Comment: sorry if its not clear. What I really want to achieve is to pass the value of an input from account() to another const which is on sales_add().

Comment: You should pass the data on component prop

Answer (score 0):

Its not quite clear what you are trying to achieve. `sales_add` has been defined as a function, but has a `render` function defined in it with no return statement. `sales_add` looks like its being used as a functional component, and this needs a return statement. `render` belongs to class based components. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69625500/react-js-efficient-way-of-passing-data-and-to-another-constant-variable) for more info.

As I understand, you would like to pass a value to the sales_add() function, keep state, and log that state to console when it changes.

You have the definition of a [Custom Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html)

You can achieve this with slight modifications.

First, for `sales_add`, instead of using `render` which belongs to a Class based component, return the function used to set the sales value.

```
export default function sales_add() {

    const [Sales, setSales] = useState("")

      return setSales; //return setSales which is used to mutate the value of Sales
    }
```

Now, if you want to log to the console every time `Sales` changes, we can set up a [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) to watch `Sales` and do something when it changes. It is also good practice to prefix your custom hooks with 'use'. This will change your `sales_add` custom hook name to `useSalesAdd`

```
export default function useSalesAdd() {

    const [Sales, setSales] = useState("")

    useEffect(() => {
      console.log(Sales)
    },[Sales]) //sales in the dependency array of the useEffect

      return setSales; //return setSales which is used to manipulate the value of Sales
    }
```

our Custom Hook looks good. So now we use it.

```
import useSalesAdd from "pages/Sales-Add/index";

export default function Account(){
    const setSales = useSalesAdd(); //this gets the setSales function from the custom hook!
    const onchangeValue = async (e) => {
        setSales(e.target.value) //use the function from your custom hook
    }
    return(
        <Input type="text" className="form-control" onChange={(e) => { onchange(e) }}/>
    )
}
```

Note how in the account function,

- Changed the name of the function to start with an upper case letter, which is good practice for functional components
- Changes the render to a return, which is the correct statement for a functional component. (functional components return JSX)

to recap:

- `sales_add` was converted to a custom hook, `useSalesAdd` with a return instead of a render
- `account` changed to uppercase as `Account` with return instead of render, which is correct for functional components

Answer (score 0):

Pass the data through component. If they are on same parent component it would be like this.

```
export default function account ({setState}){
    render(
        <Input type="text" className="form-control" onChange={(e) => 
        setState(e.target.value) }/>
    )
}

export default function sales_add({inputValue}) {
    render(
        <h1>{inputValue}</h1>
    )
}
```

Parent component

```
export default function Parent() {
    const [state,setState] = useState("");
    render(
        <Sales_ADD inputValue={state}/>
        <Account setState={setState}/>
    )
}
```

It will work if they are components and have same parent component, from where you can pass data. As it looks like `next js` structure, I would suggest using a single page, where you can load these two components. If you need to keep them in seperate pages, then you need to use state management tools such as `context api` or `redux`